# BrokerUnreachableException

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I am currently working on a project(**.NET**) which is using **Rabbit MQ** broker. I have been facing with `BrokerUnreachableException` for no reason.
I know when the server ip address or any other parameters are wrong we get such exception. But everything is absolutely right and some time 
I get no exception and queue operates fine with even `50K` RECORDS and sometimes it fails fr even 20 records and shows `brokerUnreachableException`.

This is very weird and unusual. 
If anyone did come through such problem or have a solution comment here!

**Scenario:**

I get a record from database, after validation I enqueue it **Rabbit MQ**. I open the connection, channel and than close both channel and connection each time I get a new record.

The same thing repeats for around 250K records.

For some duration of the day the queue works best and accepts 50K with no exception .
But there is something that goes wrong at some point of time and even fr 10 records iI get the broker unreachable exception

Comment: did you check the broker logs? 
is it enough restart your .NET application, or  you have also to restart RMQ?

Comment: did you ever figure out what was happening? Similar thing is happening to us.

Comment: HEy guys i have the solved my issue. and I am no more getting any exception. Data is pulled very fast at a rate of 250K records per 15 secs.